# SODA '15 Page Limits

Tags: conferences

The [SODA '15 submission rules](http://www.siam.org/meetings/da15/submissions.php) state that "The submission, excluding title page, bibliography and appendix, must not exceed 10 pages."

However, the website does not define "title page." Does "title page" simply mean "the page with the title and abstract," or does it mean some sort of cover page?

Comment: Just title, names and affiliations, and abstract. BTW I think this kind of question is too narrow for this site.

Comment: @SashoNikolov Although you are right it is too narrow, I find it hard to imagine where else one could ask and expect to get the correct answer quickly.

Comment: You can email and ask them.

Comment: @Kaveh It's Sunday and the final deadline is tomorrow.  This is what the web/stackexchange is made for.  I would leave the question (and the answer in the comment) up until the deadline at least.

Comment: @Kaveh I don't think it's similar to troubleshooting TeX installation.  The question is in one sense of direct relevant to almost all active CS theory researchers.  If it is closed and this makes it less likely for people to find it, that seems like a bad thing to me.  By the way, the people on tex.stackexchange.com are almost infinitely helpful . See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files for example.

Comment: @Lembik, closing does not remove it from search results. As I wrote I don't see much difference between this and seeking help for other things like installing TeX. cstheory is not an announcement board, you can tweet it or post it on a blog or a mailing list or a website or G+ ... if you want to make it easier for people to find.

Comment: @Lembik You should look at the published proceedings for the previous years and see what the title page and etc looks like...

Comment: @TayfunPay The formatting for submission and publishing are quite different so this doesn't help. "SIAM will provide final paper submission instructions to authors of accepted papers in mid-September 2014. Final papers may not exceed twenty (20) pages in double column format." I also didn't ask the question :)

Comment: I would hope the PC chair would be responsive to queries right before the deadline. I did not downvote and I sympathize with the OP, but my impression is that very narrow questions are not encouraged here.

Answer (score 2):

I emailed the PC and received the following answer:

> "Title  page" means a page that contains only the title and abstract.

Comment: Presumably also the author names and affiliations. I agree, this could have been made more clear. I had some co-authors (who have not had a lot of past SODA papers) ask the same thing (it was not obvious to them whether the abstract could be included in the title page).